# Find package name from full class name (without reference to that class)

Tags: android

Is there a simple way to determine a package name of the application with the given full class name of the activity.

For example lets assume that some app (**not my app**) has this class `com.example.test.ui.MyActivity`
And lets also assume that package name of that application is `com.example.test`

So my question is, is there a way to get a package name of that application without trying all possibilities.

This is what i have so far, is there a simpler way.

```
public static String findPackageForActivity(Context context, String activity)
{
    /*com.google.android.apps.messaging.ui.ConversationListActivity*/
    String[] parts = activity.split("\\.");
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(activity) || parts.length < 2)return null;
    int splitIndex = parts.length - 1;
    for(int i = splitIndex; i > 1; --i)
    {
        activity = activity.substring(0, activity.lastIndexOf("."));
        if(isApplicationInstalled(context, activity))return activity;
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isApplicationInstalled(Context context, String packageName)
{
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try
    {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope. Because you can have an Activity with the class name "my.big.brother.is.a.dog.MyActivity" in an app whose package name is "x.y.z.a.b.c".